# Vários input file modificado na mesma página com JQuery

Tags: jquery, input

Estou tentando fazer **vários** *input file* na mesma página onde no campo *input type="text"* apareça o nome do arquivo quando selecionado ou poder digitar diretamente o nome do arquivo. Até aí está perfeito, com um único input/botão está funcionando do jeito que desejo. O problema é fazer **vários** *inputs*, no caso 6, na mesma página que não estou conseguindo. Não é selecionar vários arquivos com o mesmo botão e sim 6 campos *input text* com 6 *botões* que cada botão que eu clicar, eu selecione um arquivo. Coloquei uma imagem para facilitar o entendimento. Uso o jquery-3.6.4.min. Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
<style type="text/css">

.arquivo {
    display: none;
}

.file {
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 300px;
}

.btn {
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    background-color: #4493c7;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 32px;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
    $('.arquivo').trigger('click');
});

$(document).on('change', '.arquivo', function() {
    var fileName = $(this)[0].files[0].name;
    $('#file').val(fileName);
});

</script>

HTML:

<input class="arquivo" id="arquivo" name="arquivo" type="file">
<input class="file" id="file" name="file" type="text">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="...">
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode usar o `insertAdjacentHTML`  ou `createElement` ou até mesmo o   `innerHTML`  em um loop lhe causaria o resultado esperado

Answer (score -3):

Para adicionar várias entradas de arquivos na mesma página, você precisa fazer algumas modificações. Em vez de usar IDs para os elementos de entrada, você pode usar classes e atualizar suas funções jQuery para trabalhar com elementos relacionados.

Passos:

1. Atualizar os atributos **id** para **class** nos elementos de
   entrada, pois você deseja ter várias entradas de arquivos na mesma
   página.
2. Atualizar os seletores jQuery no JavaScript para funcionar com classes em
   vez de IDs.
3. Modificar a função de clique do botão para selecionar o elemento de entrada de
   arquivo relacionado usando **$(this).prevAll('.arquivo').first()** em vez de
   selecionar todos os elementos **.arquivo**.
4. Modificar a função de mudança do arquivo para atualizar o elemento de entrada
   de texto relacionado usando **$(this).next('.file')** em vez de selecionar todos
   os elementos **#file**.

HTML:

```
<input class="arquivo" name="arquivo[]" type="file">
<input class="file" name="file[]" type="text">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="...">
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
        $(this).prevAll('.arquivo').first().trigger('click');
    });

    $(document).on('change', '.arquivo', function() {
        var fileName = $(this)[0].files[0].name;
        $(this).next('.file').val(fileName);
    });
</script>
```

Agora você pode adicionar mais conjuntos de entradas conforme necessário, e cada botão funcionará com seu campo de entrada de arquivo correspondente.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8842/conte%c3%bado-gerado-por-chatgpt-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-permitido-na-rede?cb=1